# Поздняя загрузка CSS

Tags: html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

Всем добрый день. столкнулся с проблемой CSS стили подгружаются с задержкой тоесть заходя на сайт сначала загружается вся хтмл разметка а потом через доли секунд или может пару секунд CSS и все становится как надо. как решить подобную проблему впервые с ней столкнулся.

Comment: Подключаете внутри тега <head></head>? Что Firebug говорит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместить стили наверх страницы между тэгами `<head>...</head>`. Исключить `@import` в `css`. Возможно в том же `head` есть подключенные скрипты, которые блокируют `css`. Их нужно переместить вниз страницы переде `</body>/`

Comment: Вот импорт есть а все остальное скрипты внизу как положено и стилей вне Хеада нет думаю проблема в импорте. Спасибо